# Autoplay JWplayer when loading rss feed

Tags: jquery, jwplayer

I am loading an RSS playlist but I can not seem to get this to autostart or autoplay.

If I run `jwplayer().load('playlist_demo.rss').play();` it doesnt work, and if I run

`jwplayer().play('playlist_demo.rss')` it doesnt load the playlist, it just plays the player..

What am I missing? I tried using a callback `onReady(function ({ jwplayer.play() )}` but still no luck

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: I am running this from an `onClick` of an `li` item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
jwplayer().load('playlist_demo.rss');
jwplayer().play();
```

Comment: I tried to add playlist via rss dynamically by this <code> way,jwplayer().load("/music/feed?name=default")
  jwplayer().play() </code> , so by the load method , I am loading my content . But it is not playing, no errors at all., please help me out

Comment: Please provide a link.